# codeigniter session is lost once I redirect to another controller

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, session

I have a problem with sessions at codegniter , it seems to be strange for me !

it works when I logged from the database , but when I logged from Facebook/twitter Api , it appears only at the "sociallog" controller that I check if this social account logged before or not !

I debugged my code with

```
echo "print all data at the session ".print_r($this->session->all_userdata())."\n";
```

at the "sociallog" controller

```
 Array
 (
[session_id] => 36356242e5b0f3f0e25e6e0d5f5ca22c
[ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
[user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
[last_activity] => 1402828004
[user_data] => 
[username] => mary
[id] => 2
[img] => images/profile/0a92617b105ccb08eabcde613eab9cde.jpg
[mail] => al@al.com
[criedt] => 0
[services_no] => 2
[job] => marketeer
[logged_in] => 1
 )
```

But when I redirect to the home controller

```
echo "print all data at the session ".print_r($this->session->all_userdata())."\n";
```

the output is

```
Array
(
[session_id] => d0f0f2afab107dd75ecf056b79066bbe
[ip_address] => ::1
[user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
[last_activity] => 1402828385
[user_data] =>  
)
```

that mean I lost all the data that loaded at the session

I really get to the madness of it !
the same problem with chrome / firefox and /IE

when I logged from the database directly it works fine with me , I don't know if the problem is that the controller redirect to fb api and then back with the data that I load to the session !

any suggestions for that !

Comment: Did you try to extend the home controller with the sociallog controller, instead of CI_Controller?

Comment: @Cristian , I got error for that "Fatal error: Class 'home' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\rungears.com\application\controllers\sociallog.php on line 3" I have tried to make nested classes at the same file but the same problem  , thanks alot for trying to help cris , I will keep trying to solve it !

Comment: can you post your controller codes?

Comment: this is the sociallog controller http://shar.es/P8aZe and the authentication controller  http://shar.es/P8aOv

Comment: i've noticed you use session_start(), you don't have to use it.. your framework does it for you..

Comment: I have tried to use native session at the logging from fb and twitter  "that I got from 'sociallog' controller" and pass it to the  'authentication'  controller with the header request , and then it goes well with codegniter session , I will try to share here the script I did once I finalize or fix this bug in a less buggy script , thanks a million for your help,cris

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while working with multiple databases, the solution that worked for me was:

I loaded the database manually where ever it is required, and turned of the session saving to the database option, you can try turning off the session saving option in codeigniter and check if it works and try manually loading the database as well, might not be too much of a solution but it worked for me :)

Comment: I did it by working with  native php session then at the controller I get the data from the native session to the framework session

Answer (score 0):

Use Database session. for that.

Change in Config.php

```
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
```

and add One table in Database.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
  `session_id` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_agent` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `last_activity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_data` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`),
  KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```